# Set htaccess to different directories

Tags: .htaccess

I need to configure my htaccess so that it can be answered in two different ways.
Ex: foo.com access the path /foo (foo.com only) and when;
foo.com/any access the path /internal.
How can I do this?

Comment: I had to use a route control for my php

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^foo$ foo.com [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-z_-]+)$ /internal [QSA,L,NC]
```

This resource might help you:
[Ask Apache](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/#Rewrite_to_www)

You could use whatever was typed and print in the url as a variable
like:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-z_-]+)$ /internal?area=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Sorry for not adding a detail!
/any is variable and not fixed

Comment: edited my answer to match your needs... the regex catches any `([0-9A-z_-]+)` alphanumeric characters, underscore and hifen...